# Can I make a link on my page point at another link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have a internally run html site consisting of an index.htm and several sub pages. On these sub pages I link to files on our server (e.g. word documents, excel sheets and others). My issue is that many of my sub pages link to the same file so that when I change the filename I have to edit ALL my links on ALL my sub pages. e.g. *sub1.htm* has a link to *text1.docx* and so does *sub5.htm* and *sub12.htm*, if I then change the name of the word file to *text1_ver2.docx* I need to edit my links on all my sub pages.

Is there a way to have all sub pages links point at a main link and only having to edit this one main link?

I hope to have a single sub page - let's call it *links.htm* - with a list of all my `href="text1.docx"` links and then my other href's on sub pages should simply point to the correct link on my *links.htm*. Then I only need to edit the destionation on the *links.htm*...

Answer (score 2):

You could create a variable in javascript with the url you are referring to like so:

```
<script>
   var hrefLink = "your_url.com";
   // Set the href attribute with your url
   document.getElementById('word_link').setAttribute('href', hrefLink);
</script>
```

In your html code you would simply do the following:

```
<a id='word_link'>Link</a>
```

With this way of coding you will only have to change the url at one place and it will give the same href to all elements with the id 'word_link'. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Why don't you use JS for that? There should be ways without that too, but if you know basic JS you should use it and you will have no problem later editing it.

Comment: @NikaJobava Hopefully this will help him out!

Comment: @NikaJobava I am a noob at this but I am still the one with most experience in html at my work... However I have no knowledge of JaveScript...
Where do I enter the <script>var...<\script>? In the sub1htm or in the links.htm?

Comment: @MartinHL A better way to achieve it is to create a javascript file and put the javascript code I provided in the .js file without the script tags and refer to it in each html file like: <script src=''my-js-file.js" /> so the javascript code will be the same for each file.

Comment: @MartinHL You should put the `<script>` tag at the end of the `<body>` tag if you use an external file. Otherwise, you can put it anywhere, but your problem will stay the same because if you use internal js, you will have to change all of the files by hand. So I recommend creating a link.js file and using `<script src="path"> </script>` at end of all htm files. Make sure you will put correct path in it.

Comment: @NikaJobava and AntonioSkopin I think this will be my way of making it work. Thanks.
Seems I need to start learning som JavaScript if I want to make our html site more advanced

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use PHP or JS !
Html is not dynamic :)
Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You really don't have to go through the pain of editing and changing the file names; that can bring about complications.
Simply use JavaScript.